# Eclipse prevents me from checking out a branch by asking me to commit .class and .gitignore files

Tags: java, eclipse, git

Eclipse prevents me from checking out a branch by asking me to commit .class and autogenerated .gitignore file.
.gitignore is set to prevent those .class files to be versioned. I've already removed them with rm -r --cached . but eclipse keeps telling me it can't checkout because of uncommitted change (useless to say that committing them is not a solution).

However, if I checkout from bash, everything's ok.

What's happening?

Comment: What change does it say is uncommited?  What does `git status` show?

Comment: git status say everything is ok, all up-to-date and nothing to commit, while eclipse says:"the files shown below have uncommitted changes which would be lost by checking out..' 'Either commit the changes etc.'

Comment: I'm not an expertise on git, but I know very well the SVN and usually when this kind of thing happens we run a clean-up on that folder and eclipse works fine. Maybe you have such a command on git?!

Comment: The Git plugin in eclipse is buggy at best... why don't you try the command line client for git or some guis like TortoiseGit / Git extensions (Windows) or Git cola (linux)?

Comment: Add those unwanted files to svn ignore. those files won't be asked during check-in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the extensions of unwanted files to .gitignore file.

See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files